# How to change MySQL max_connections_per_hour without credentials?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I physically own the computer which my database is running on.

I set `max_connections_per_hour` for user `root` to `1` now I'm locked out of phpMyAdmin for an hour.

I logged in as the user `pma` but it doesn't have permissions to `ALTER` users to I can't modify the `max_conections_per_hour`, being locked out.

I need a way to change settings without credentials, or a way to create a new user with all permissions, without actually being logged in.

I'm on Windows.

Comment: You can't, or shouldn't be able to. That would be a big security flaw if any user could make themselves super.

Comment: I should be allowed to edit some configuration file.  After all, the computer is physically in my possession.

Comment: The application is not. You can remove and reinstall mysql.

Comment: Sadly that is what I have had to resort to.

Comment: ... you could wait < 25 minutes and it should unlock itself again.You then can correct your error.

Comment: In an alternative universe ...